# Changing the Total Number of Recent Files

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, recent-file-list

I'd like the user to be able to edit the number of recent files shown in the File menu of my MFC application.  I've used two very good references:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/changemru.aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0899/c/c0899.aspx

It involves deleting and recreating the `CRecentFileList` object stored in `CWinApp::m_pRecentFileList`. Unfortunately, I find that the menu is not updated properly after replacing the `CRecentFileList`. See code snippet below:

```
void CMyWinApp::SetMRUListSize( int size )
{
   // size guaranteed to be between 1 and 16
   delete m_pRecentFileList ;
   LoadStdProfileSettings( size ) ;
}
```

What can I do to ensure that what is drawn into the File menu is synchronized with `m_pRecentFileList` after I recreate the object?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will helps but I had problems with MFC RecentFileList and Windows 7 where I needed to call the function SetRegistryKey before the call to LoadStdProfileSettings (see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921231/maintaining-a-recent-files-list/1922749#1922749). Not sure if this is related to your problem though.

Answer (score 3):

My CApp derives from CWinApp. In initInstance, you have this line:

```
LoadStdProfileSettings(10);
```

At the end of InitInstance, add this code:

```
m_pmf->m_pRecentFileList = m_pRecentFileList;
```

Here m_pmf is my MainFrame class and I created a member CMainFrame::m_pRecentFileList of type CRecentFileList which is in the MFC source file filelist.cpp.  m_pRecentFileList on the right is protected and CMainFrame doesn't have access to it from outside InitInstance, but you can make a functional copy here.

At the end of CMainFrame::OnClose, force a registry update by:

```
           m_pRecentFileList->WriteList();
```

// Force registry update on exit.  This doesn't work without forcing.

I don't even have to rebuild m_pRecentFileList, the MRU mechanism updates it correctly.  Example: 5 MRU items, the first is moved to another directory and can no longer be found. Stepping through the code in the debugger shows that the bad entry is removed from the list. For some reason, the updated list isn't saved correctly unless I force it as explained above. I originally thought the problem might have something to do with privileges (64-bit Win7), but running the app as admin didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

[Some of Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbkh2k4h(VS.80).aspx) suggest you should call `CWinApp::LoadStdProfileSettings` from within `InitInstance`. This suggests to me that it's something done once during initialisation rather than at run time.

Have you tried fully implementing the second of the two links you provided? My guess is you need to add the second part instead of the call to `CWinApp::LoadStdProfileSettings`:

```
m_pRecentFileList = new CRecentFileList(0, strSection, strEntryFormat, nCount);
if(m_pRecentFileList)
{
    bReturn = TRUE;

    // Reload list of MRU files from registry
    m_pRecentFileList->ReadList();
}
```

**[Edit]** Apparently `m_pRecentFileList` points to an [`CRecentFileList` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a5b36d5(VS.80).aspx)  . Have you tried calling [`CRecentFileList::UpdateMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs6te8ba(VS.80).aspx)?

There's [another CodeProject example which might help](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/deletemenu.aspx?fid=39099&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick) too.

Comment: You might be right - I have changed the code accordingly, but the menu is still not updating correctly after programatically changing the number of recent files. Specifically, reducing the number of recent files displayed does not reduce the total number of recent files shown.